# How to draw object array in Android OpenGL ES 'OnDrawFrame'

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es

I am going to try to draw an array of objects in the current 'OnDrawFrame'.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
     objectArray[i].draw(gl);
     }
}
```

When I try to use the 'for' statement as described above, a waste of memory seems to be too terrible.

It is removed continues even if you like that in practice, drawing objects will be displayed at the end.

By doing what, an array of objects of all or will drawn?

Also, What do I need to do to make efficient use of memory

We are troubled by leakage of what day to night.

---

Draw a line class.......

```
public class LINETEST {

float[] vertices = null;
private short[] indices = null;

public FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer; 

public LINETEST() {

}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
    gl.glLineWidth(2);
    gl.glColor4f(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, indices.length, 
              GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer); 

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

public void setBuffer() {

            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
            verticesBuffer.position(0);

            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            indexBuffer.put(indices);
            indexBuffer.position(0);            
}

public void setVertices(float[] verticesAl, short[] indicesAl){

    this.vertices = verticesAl;
    this.indices = indicesAl;       

}
```

}

---

The function that an array of objects of class above.

```
public void setVertices(float[] vertice, short[] indice, int lineNumber){
    this.vertices = vertice;
    this.indices = indice;
    this.number = lineNumber;

 linetest[number] = new LINETEST();
 linetest[number].setVertices(vertices, indices);               
 linetest[number].setBuffer();

}
```

---

Finally, it is OnDraw method to draw using the above function. It runs in the renderer class.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

     int OBJL = 30;
     switch (OBJL){
     case 30:
         if(vertices != null){
             if(linetest[number] != null){
                for(int i = 0; i<number; i++){
                    linetest[number].draw(gl);
                }
                 linetest[number].draw(gl);
             }

         }else{
             break;
         }
    }
```

}

Comment: please add the code you use to draw each object.

Comment: I create multiple objects in one class.

Comment: However, she put it by generating a random vertex array when the object is created, the position to be drawn are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `glDrawArrays()` or `glDrawElements()` for using just one GL call to render an array.

References:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

For instance:

```
// Vertices are stored in counter-clockwise order
float vertsCoords[] = {-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // V1
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // V2
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // V3
                    };

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertsCoords); // 3 components per vertex, float in size, from offset 0 at array 'vertsCoords'
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // draw 3 vertices
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

This may look like a lot of code, but you eventually just send 4 GL calls instead of at least objectArray.length calls in your case.

If you want to get even further, you could take a look at vertex buffer objects:

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/

Comment: Thank's for your answer flobo~

Comment: But, then I do not understand the code above. I created a class to draw a picture as shown in the code above. Then, by using the class created, you created a multiple array to an object of that class.

Comment: The thing I want is, of whether there is a thing how can you draw completely draw function within the object that is created as this object array.

Comment: You have put to answer the following code to create an array of object class and its in the form I made it do not know if, to draw.

Comment: Will be attached to the body on the class to draw a line that I want you to check them out on having you understand made​​, the code that make up an array of objects that class.

Comment: Sorry, I do really not understand what you mean with the five comments above. No offence, but did you translate your answers?
Also the answer I wrote was targeted your question before you posted all other code.

Comment: Sorry I will not speak English well.
Native language using Google Translator to translate English wrote one.
Thank you for your response.
Still, the complexity of the problem is the fact that.